# Can I apply for research assistantship at universities abroad?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, united-states, independent-researcher, research-assistantship

I am a recent master's graduate looking for a job. However, instead of working in the industry, I would prefer to work for a couple of years as a research assistant. My long-term goal is to apply for a Ph.D. program and research experience will help me get there.

My country is very limited in such opportunities which will act as leverage during my Ph.D. applications. Hence, I was wondering if there are universities that hire international candidates as research assistants? I will of course need visa sponsorship for that.

Working as a research assistant at a good university will let me network with known scientists in my field. Therefore, strengthening my LoRs.

Comment: Why not directly apply for PhD programs? Afaik it's much more common.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, at least, and perhaps several other places, the term "Research Assistant" is used for a position connected to doctoral education only. In some lab sciences (chemistry,...) a grant-funded lab might also hire other more permanent people, but they might be called "Lab Assistants" or "Lab Technicians" rather than Research Assistants. An RA position lasts up to the time of graduation and most of the perks involve tuition forgiveness and such, not salary.

But a lab assistant follows the direction of others and is only peripherally involved with research in the lab and so it might not even be a good place to get a LoR for a doctoral application. Such folks may be essential, but they are employees not researchers.

I doubt that such opportunities exist in Statistics *per se* as most statisticians don't work in laboratories requiring maintenance of equipment and such. Biostatistics might be different in some cases.

But if you want to get a doctorate, then applying for one (yet again) may solve your problems altogether. Again, in the US, most doctoral students at good universities are funded, either through a Teaching Assistantship or an RA.

If you were rejected already then I suggest you broaden your search. If it was a narrow search, especially one centered at top level universities then a broader search might be successful. And you may need to talk to your letter writers to see why they affect your application. The letter writers should be people who know you and your work and are willing to use their own reputation to predict your success. I've gotten at least one student over the line in a good place by letting the dean there know things that weren't reflected in the normal application materials. The person I'm thinking of is now a full professor at a top school.

Answer (score 5):

It would help to know the field you're in as there could be exceptions that I'm not aware of.

From my experience in STEM, research assistant opportunities for Master's graduates are very rare (especially so for sponsoring an international candidate). If there was funding for a research assistantship position it would usually go a PhD graduate (ie. postdoc) - international candidates are very common in this case.

Comment: My field is statistics, biostatistics, data science.